# Caching & Outputting RSS Data

Tags: rss, cache

I need to pull in 2 different RSS feeds from an external site into our site. I have two questions about how to best do this:

1. I want to cache the feed so that it doesn't get pulled in every time someone visits the site. What is the best way to go about doing that in WordPress?
2. I will need to output the data (post title and thumbnail image) for each post. What is the best way to go about doing that in WordPress?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the core function [fetch_feed()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed), your new best friend!

From the Codex:

> Retrieves an external feed and parses it. Uses the SimplePie and
>   FeedCache functionality for retrieval and parsing and automatic
>   caching.

and

> `fetch_feed` caches results for 12 hours by default. You can modify this
>   by modifying the time interval via the filter
>   `wp_feed_cache_transient_lifetime`.

Comment: Small hint. The core cached the feed inside the transient, so inside the database. If you like a cache, like object cache or what ever, then you must input more todos.